# How to use request.Context instead of CloseNotifier?

Tags: go

I am using CloseNotifier in my application, in a code that looks like this

```golang
func Handler(res http.ResonseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    notify := res.(CloseNotifier).CloseNotify()

    someLogic();
    select {
        case <-notify:
            someCleanup()
            return;
        default:
    }
    someOtherLogic();
}
```

I have noticed CloseNotifier is now deprecated. [From source code](https://golang.org/src/net/http/server.go?s=7899:8020#L208):

```
// Deprecated: the CloseNotifier interface predates Go's context package.
// New code should use Request.Context instead.
```

However, I am not sure how to use Request.Context exactly here.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LSzR0VEraWw

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems rather simple actually. [From this blogpost](https://www.sohamkamani.com/blog/golang/2018-06-17-golang-using-context-cancellation/):

```golang
func Handler(res http.ResonseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    ctx := req.Context()

    someLogic();
    select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            someCleanup(ctx.Err())
            return;
        default:
    }
    someOtherLogic();
}
```

Comment: Also useful to catch the reason for a context cancelation via: `req.Context().Err()` in the cleanup section.